# Angular: using $http without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If the point of using this sytax: `<div ng-controller="BuildingsCtrl as bc">`is to avoid using `$scope`(and apparently [it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)), then how should I go about using `$http`?

That is, how could I re-write the following code to not use $scope?

```
angular.module('atlasAngularApp')
    .controller('BuildingsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        this.awesomeThings = [
            'HTML5 Boilerplate',
            'AngularJS',
            'Karma'
        ];
        this.getBuildings = function () {
            $http.get('http://localhost:40602/api/1.0/buildings')
                .then(function successCallaback(response) {
             ======>    $scope.buildings = response.data;
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("Error");
                }
            );
       }
   });
```

To elaborate a little more,

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in bc.awesomeThings">
    {{ thing }}
</li>
```

Works fine with `this.awesomeThings`, so a view can use `this`, but the following doesn't work:

```
angular.module('atlasAngularApp')
    .controller('BuildingsCtrl', function ($http) {
        var self = this;
        this.getBuildings = function () {
            $http.get('http://localhost:40602/api/1.0/buildings')
                .then(function successCallaback(response) {
             ======>    self.buildings = response.data;
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("Error");
                }
            );
       }
   });
```

(notice the `self.buildings` bit.)

I've tried a number of variations along these lines theme, but nothing so far has worked. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641014/getting-data-from-angular-http-without-scope) question is similar, but I wasn't able to adapt it to my code.

I should probably add that I don't have anything against `$scope`, I'm just trying to do things the way yeoman-generated angular seems to approve of. I'd also like some explanation on why `$scope` could be considered a bad thing.

For completeness, here's my view. Maybe there's something wrong with it?

```
<div ng-controller="BuildingsCtrl as bc">
    <table ng-init="buildings = bc.getBuildings()">
        <tr ng-repeat="building in buildings">
            <td>{{ building.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ building.code }}</td>
            <td>{{ building.image }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The code does work, so long as I use `$scope`

Comment: what exactly is your problem? is your buildings not being rendered on the view?

Comment: Yes. Nothing appears in the view

Comment: you are binding buildings and repeating awesomethings in the view.can you show code parts for the rewrite without the use of scope

Comment: try ng-repeat="building in bc.buildings" in view and see result.

Comment: Yep. That was it, which makes perfect sense, now that I look at it. Thanks!

Comment: i will create an answer for this and the answer for scope and this.Is that okay

Comment: Please do. I hate it when the answer to a question is buried in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `ng-init="buildings = bc.getBuildings()"` but not returning anything to bind to `buildings` instead you are assigning values to `self.buildings` which is `this.buildings` indirectly. So, your repeat with `buildings` was not working. Now when you assign to `this.buildings` `bc.buildings` is what you are actually referring to in view.
So,

```
<tr ng-repeat="building in bc.buildings">
```

repeats your elements.

As for your answer to using `$scope` and `this`. There is no better explanation than here:['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, those kind of calls to a back end are not supposed to be done by the controller. You should make a service for that to get it for you.

Secondly, most of the time you see controllers like this:

```
angular.module('atlasAngularApp')
.controller('BuildingsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.awesomeThings = [
        'HTML5 Boilerplate',
        'AngularJS',
        'Karma'
    ];

    vm.getBuildings = getBuildings;



    function getBuildings() {
        $http.get('http://localhost:40602/api/1.0/buildings')
            .then(function successCallaback(response) {
                vm.buildings = response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    alert("Error");
            }
        );
   }
});
```

Like that you can loop over the buildings of vm in your html:

```
<li ng-repeat="building in bc.buildings">
   {{ building }}
</li>
```

A good resource to look at in terms of best practices is the styleguide of John Papa: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: I pasted in your controller and got the same result. There's data in the view if I use `$scope.buildings`, there's nothing if I use`vm.buildings`. The view is up top now too. Maybe there's something wrong with it?